# max-width does not work for table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

I have a table with 3 cells in each row. This is my CSS:

```
table.result {
  width: 100%;
}

.result td:nth-child(3n+1) {
  width: 10%;
  max-width: 50px;
}

.result td:nth-child(3n+2) {
  width: 33%;
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

The table's first cell width is `10%` (`187px`) and the second `td` is `33%` (`618px`) and setting `max-width` does not work.

The idea is to have a 100% width table and the third cell have the rest width

```css
table.result {
  width: 100%;
}

.result td:nth-child(3n+1) {
  width: 10%;
  max-width: 50px;
}

.result td:nth-child(3n+2) {
  width: 33%;
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<table class="result" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Row</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Description</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan I added the snippet.

Comment: `max-width` doesn't work on table cells. Add an inner element, i.e. a `div`, and give it the `max-width`

Comment: @LGSon well after that , how to prevent table cell from growing?

Comment: If you give the extra element a max-width of 50px, it won't grow and then the cell won't either. Or did I misunderstood you?

Comment: well the `div` does not grow but td grows. I now have a td of 658px with a 24px div in it

Comment: Your table is set to `width: 100%`, and a cell having `width: 10%` will be 10 percent of the table, so if the table's width is the same as the viewport and the viewport is 1600px, your cell will be 160px, no matter the max-width on an inner `div`. If this is an issue, you need to give us a better sample of what you want to achieve, maybe with a drawing. Also, what is the `nth-child(3n+1)` for? ... Are there many cells in a row and every 3rd should have a given width/max-width?

Comment: @LGSon please have a look at this: [https://jsfiddle.net/t1er88rs/](https://jsfiddle.net/t1er88rs/). isn't it what you are suggesting?

Comment: No, I suggest the `div` should have `max-width`: https://jsfiddle.net/t1er88rs/1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151086/discussion-between-ashkan-mobayen-khiabani-and-lgson).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By adding a `div` to each cell and use `max/min-width` on the those, you can control the cells better, here is a sample

```css
table.result {
  width: 100%;
}

.result td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 100%;
}

.result td:nth-child(1) div {
  min-width: 40px;
  max-width: 50px;
}

.result td:nth-child(2) div {
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<table class="result" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        Row
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        Name
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>Description</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Another option is to use Flexbox, and it could look like this

```css
.result {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.result > div {
  display: flex;
}

.result > div > div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.result > div > div:nth-child(1) {
  flex-basis: 40px;                  /*  40px width  */
  max-width: 50px;
}

.result > div > div:nth-child(2) {
  flex-basis: 100px;                 /*  100px width  */
  max-width: 150px;
}

.result > div > div:nth-child(3) {
  flex-grow: 1;                      /*  fill the rest of the space  */
}
```

```html
<div class="result">
  <div>
    <div>
      Row
    </div>
    <div>
      Name
    </div>
    <div>
      Description
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using Flex to adjust the width of each table element. 
You can find more information here: 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/